# BigDecimal - material decimal places

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal value and I want to know if the number of decimal places it has is outside a boundary.

> e.g. If BigDecimal is 123.456 and my decimal places boundary is 2 then
>   this would be an error
>
> However 123.450 with a boundary of 2 is ok as I consider the 0 to be immaterial for this test.

I am a bit unsure about BigDecimal with it's scale/unscaled implementation.

I have looked at `scale()` as an option but I think this could be wrong for my case where trailing zeros are concerned.

Does anyone know the correct way to test for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal` has `stripTrailingZeros()`. After that `scale()` will do what you want.

OR you could use `BigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY)` which will throw an Exception if there are non-zeros. To me this looks a bit inefficient in the common case. But if you would throw an exception anyway it might be useful.